# logrotate fails to rotate logs: error setting owner

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, users, group, logrotate

Recently I've noticed that `logrotate` does not rotate my logs.

`user1@host:~$ /usr/sbin/logrotate /home/user1/logrotate.conf -v` gives me an error:

`error: error setting owner of /home/logs/mylog.log.1 to uid 10111 and gid 10111: Operation not permitted
error: error creating output file /var/lib/logrotate/status.tmp: Permission denied`

That `gid` confuses me, as `user1` is only a member of a group with different gid:

`user1@host:~$ id
uid=10111(user1) gid=1001(mygroup) groups=1001(mygroup)`

However, there's another group called `user1`, but, as I mentioned, actual user `user1` is not its member:

`user1@host:~$ cat /etc/group | grep user1
user1:x:10111`

It's something simple here, but I can't see it.

UPDATE:
here's what logrotate.conf looks like:

`/home/logs/*.log {
    rotate 7
    daily
    copytruncate
    compress
    notifempty
 }`

*logrotate 3.8.7*

UPDATE 2:

`user1@host:~$ ls -la /home/logs/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 mygroup 1358383344 Dec 19 00:58 mylog.log`

Comment: Can you add the corresponding stanza of your `logrotate.conf`? (Oh,and also your version of logrotate, just in case.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz just updated the question, thanks.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -l /home/user1/*.log`

Comment: @wurtel nothing suspicious there, just updated. thanks.

Comment: Why is it trying to set group to 10111 if the log file itself is in group 1001(mygroup); that's what you need to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with a different user, one having default group membership: for each user userx there is membership in a distinct userx group. If logrotate is successful with different user account, then apply similar group membership settings for the user1 account having difficulty.